# PG conflict changing the name of an attribute in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-migration, model-associations

I'm having an issue after changing the name in a "Relationship" Controller and Model (the name is "follow / unfollow" and before was "meaw / unmeaw" (which I endend founding pretty bad and got back to something more classic). I also changed it in the database and many other places, but PostGres displays an error message as follow :

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column relationships.meawed_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" WHERE "relations...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" WHERE "relationships"."meawed_id" = $1 LIMIT $2
```

I wonder if I have to take care of this with another migration or directly using PG interface... The problem is that I don't remember the password or how to authenticate. I thought it might be better to reset the database.

Comment: You are still using `"meawed_id"`in your query. Either way, you'll *need* access to your db eventually.

Comment: Ok... Maybe the best way would be to reset the db. I don't have much inthere so I guess it could be my best choice what do you think ?